# How to do an If on swipe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, swipe

I want to do a if on swipe then do this otherwise do something else but i cant seem to get it working?

JS:

```
if ($("p").on("swipe") == true)
{
  alert("You swiped!");
}
else
{
  //Stuff
}
```

Comment: What is going wrong then?

Comment: I dont get my alert / code doesnt run in the if (When swiped)

Comment: Please read [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/). You can see `handler` argument (type of function), which is not optional ...

Comment: I read that and others but cant seem to get it working. I want a listener or something to go, If swiping then enter else do other stuff.

Comment: "_If swiping then enter else do other stuf_" That is not possible, you can detect a swipe, but how to detect an else case, and when? I'm afraid you've to rethink the logic of your program. Get familiar with event model, it will help you to achieve what you actually need.

Comment: ...and make sure you have jquery mobile loaded. `swipe` is not a standard jQuery event. You need mobile to make this work

Comment: I have code that does stuff but its on a swipe interface so you can swipe to different slides, but if i try to swipe on a specific content it moves that element.. I want to go, if swipe then dont enter that code, otherwise run it like normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a touchdown and touchup event that checks the `Y & X coordinates` and if they are == on the touchend then its a click, else.. Swipe.

Brief Code:

```
x = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX; //<-- In a function like function(e){}
//Same for y.
y = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
if (x == y)
{
  //Click
}
else
{
  //Swipe
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this instead:

```
$("p").on("swipe", function(){ 
    alert("You swiped!"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `swipe` event properly.

```
$("selector").on("swipe",function(event){
    console.log(event.handled); //Check this 
})
```

[Swipe Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_swipe.asp)

Comment: You can do it by applying `.addClass` then check if element has that class or not.

Comment: @irishwill200 You can also check `$(this)` to see if it has a class or id if your selector is generic.